# Attaching arbitrary data to objects in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

This relates mostly with what a "best practice" would be with D3.js. I want to attach arbitrary information to different svg elements that I have on a page, after they are created. In D3, it looks like one generally generates svg elements from a dataset. I want to attach data to these svg elements at any time, without adding their HTML attributes.

Is there a good way of doing this? Do I need to use an auxillary array/object or is there a way to apply data to the elements themselves?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [datum method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum) if you want to attach arbitrary data:

```
D3.select('#mynodeId').datum( mydata );
```

And then later you could access the value again:

```
var mydata = D3.select('#mynodeId').datum();
```

Internally, D3 is going to use the `__data__` property of the node, just like it does when the nodes were created from a data set via the `selectAll`, `enter`, `append` sequence.

Note that if you already have a reference to a DOM node you can pass it as the parameter to `D3.select` rather than making it re-look-up based on selector syntax:

```
D3.select( anExistingDOMNodeReference ).datum( mydata );
```

From [the API doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select):

> **d3.select(node):** Selects the specified node. This is useful if you already have a reference to a node, such as d3.select(this) within an event listener, or a global such as document.body.